# My Player Movement is presenting some Issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm starting to learn C# with Unity and I guess my code present some issues, the movement of my player works but not that good. Let me explain, I have a player at the bottom of the screen, moving only from left to right by itself, using transform.translate (I didn't used rigidbody) because on collision with the sides it stops, and is not a constant movement, the idea is that, once collides with the sides, it changes of direction, but same velocity.

The issue happens when the player colides with the walls (removed the mesh renderer to keep them transparent) but if at the same time you press the key to trigger also the change of direction the player gets stuck at the corner, as shown on this gif example:

[image: player gets stuck]

Wait for the Player to get stuck at the corners, the gif takes like 15 secs.

And here's my actual Script for the Player

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

public float playerSpeed = 8.0f;

void Update()
{
    float moveX = playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    transform.Translate(moveX, 0, 0);

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        playerSpeed = playerSpeed * -1;
    }

}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision target)
{
    if (target.gameObject.tag.Equals("SideWalls") == true)
    {
        playerSpeed = playerSpeed * -1;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok for what you want to achieve. Unfortunately, in Unity it may not be enough to pin point the problem, as the code heavily depends on the setting from the editor. One possible solution to this or similar problems:

If you still have blocking colliders, (The collision functions need some sort of rigidbody.), or if you clamp your player's position, to stop overflow, the following can happen:

- Collider on right side is hit
- Player direction change to left
- Space is hit *while colliders are still touching*
- Player direction change to right again
- There is no collider on right side left to *start* the colliderEnter event again.

In this case block your space recognition while the player is touching one side.

Comment: I've tried this but is not working 

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision target)
    {
        if (target.gameObject.tag.Equals("SideWalls"))
        {
            toiletteSpeed = toiletteSpeed * -1;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision target)
    {
        if (target.gameObject.tag.Equals("SideWalls"))
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                toiletteSpeed = toiletteSpeed * -1;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: is there a way to do this with velocity or AddForce with a constant movement? without slowing down? @AyJayKay

Comment: The enter and exit methods get called once in the frames of exiting or entering. You could use OnCollisionStay and save a flag `isTouching` or something. You need to suppress the space recognition in you update loop not on one of the collider methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you change direction when you hit the wall, but you press Space at just the right time, you'd end up inside the wall a bit most likely. Then it'd keep thinking it was entering the wall collision and reversing direction over and over. Here's what I'd do.

```
public class PMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

private List<GameObject> Collisions = new List<GameObject>();
public float playerSpeed = 8.0f;

void Update()
{
    float moveX = playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    transform.Translate(moveX, 0, 0);

    if (Collisions.Count <= 0 && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        playerSpeed = playerSpeed * -1;
    }

}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision target)
{
    if (!Collisions.Contains(target.gameObject) && target.gameObject.tag.Equals("SideWalls") == true)
    {
        Collisions.Add(target.gameObject);
        playerSpeed = playerSpeed * -1;
    }
}


void OnCollisionExit(Collision target)
{
    if (Collisions.Contains(target.gameObject)) {
        Collisions.Remove(target.gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

By keeping a list of wall objects you're inside, you can disallow the space bar if you're inside a wall. Keep in mind there's probably better ways to do the things you're doing, but this should fix the issue you're having for now.

Comment: I believe there is a typo: You can't define the same method twice. :) If you meant exit when removing from you list:
The key is omitting the space input, yes, but not because the direction change is triggered back and forth: The enter and exit methods will not be called every frame while colliders are touching.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Also I know that enter is only called when entering and exit is only called when exiting. However, if the player collides with the wall, changes direction, then hits space to change direction again before the collision is fully exited, then depending on the way the wall collider is set up it is possible for them to get sort of stuck in the wall. Could easily be tested with a debug log in OnCollisionEnter or something.